InfoPath Form /SharePoint List with Hyperlink Column that doesn't refresh unless entry is edited
I am trying to have a URL column in my SharePoint List that:

links to the specific project
is still a clickable link when exported to Excel and
doesn't break our automatic refresh in Tableau

The best way I found so far is:
I went into the InfoPath form and added a URL field with the data type of URL Type. I used the formula option to concat("https://examplewebsite=", ID). I selected the "Refresh value when formula is recalculated" box as it doesn't do anything if I don't select this.
However, what I have noticed is that the field only automatically populates if a users goes into the specific entry and hits save. Also, for brand new entries it populates the https://examplewebsite= part of the formula but is missing the ID info because the ID is assigned after the form is submitted so you have to edit the entry to get the ID to show in the URL link.
